# Synchornize between Domino Directory and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, lotus-domino

I want to ask about Error when i want to synchronize between Active Directory and Domino Directory

I did Integrating Domino Directory and Active Directory with the refrence below

http://www.duffbert.com/duffbert/blog.nsf/Images/TADF-82654W/$File/SHOW106.pdf

1. When I want to synchronize AD to Domino, i got an error like shown below**

   08:05:11,150 INFO  - [DeleteDomino] CTGDKC096I Opening Session to Domino Server: Session Type='LocalClient',, Hostname='192.168.110.210', User ID='null', Requested IIOP/SSL='false'. 
   08:05:11,525 INFO  - [DeleteDomino] CTGDKC095I Session to Domino Server is created. 
   08:05:11,525 INFO  - [DeleteDomino] CTGDKC012I Sucessfully connected to Domino Server: Name='', Version='Release 9.0.1|October 14, 2013             ', Platform='Windows/32'. 
   08:05:11,571 INFO  - [DeleteDomino] CTGDKC018I Successfully opened the Administration Requests Database: admin4.nsf. 
   08:05:11,571 INFO  - [UpdateDomino] CTGDKC096I Opening Session to Domino Server: Session Type='LocalClient',, Hostname='192.168.110.210', User ID='null', Requested IIOP/SSL='false'. 
   08:05:11,571 INFO  - [UpdateDomino] CTGDKC095I Session to Domino Server is created. 
   08:05:11,571 INFO  - [UpdateDomino] CTGDKC012I Sucessfully connected to Domino Server: Name='', Version='Release 9.0.1|October 14, 2013             ', Platform='Windows/32'. 
   08:05:11,603 INFO  - [UpdateDomino] CTGDKC018I Successfully opened the Administration Requests Database: admin4.nsf. 
   08:05:11,603 INFO  - CTGDIS087I Iterating. 
   08:05:11,759 ERROR - [DeleteDomino] CTGDIS810E handleException - cannot handle exception , delete 
   java.lang.Exception: [DeleteDomino] CTGDIS047W Entry not found. 
          at com.ibm.di.server.Log.exception(Log.java:1192) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLineComponent.delete(AssemblyLineComponent.java:1596) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.msExecuteNextConnector(AssemblyLine.java:3689) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainStep(AssemblyLine.java:3308) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainLoop(AssemblyLine.java:2944) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainLoop(AssemblyLine.java:2927) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeAL(AssemblyLine.java:2896) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.run(AssemblyLine.java:1296) 
   08:05:11,774 ERROR - CTGDIS266E Error in NextConnectorOperation. Exception occurred: java.lang.Exception: [DeleteDomino] CTGDIS047W Entry not found. 
   java.lang.Exception: [DeleteDomino] CTGDIS047W Entry not found. 
          at com.ibm.di.server.Log.exception(Log.java:1192) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLineComponent.delete(AssemblyLineComponent.java:1596) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.msExecuteNextConnector(AssemblyLine.java:3689) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainStep(AssemblyLine.java:3308) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainLoop(AssemblyLine.java:2944) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainLoop(AssemblyLine.java:2927) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeAL(AssemblyLine.java:2896) 
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.run(AssemblyLine.java:1296) 
   08:05:11,774 INFO  - CTGDIS100I Printing the Connector statistics. 
   08:05:11,774 INFO  -  [ADChanges] Get:1 
   08:05:11,774 INFO  -  [IF delete] Branch True:1, Branch False:0 
   08:05:11,774 INFO  -  [DeleteDomino] Errors:1 
   08:05:11,790 INFO  -  [ELSE - add or modify] Branch True:0, Branch False:0 
   08:05:11,790 INFO  -  [UpdateDomino] Not used 
   08:05:11,790 INFO  - CTGDIS104I Total: Get:1, Errors:2. 
   08:05:11,790 INFO  - CTGDIS101I Finished printing the Connector statistics. 
   08:05:11,790 ERROR - CTGDIS077I Failed with error: [DeleteDomino] CTGDIS047W Entry not found..
2. When I want to synchronize  Domino to AD, I Got an Error like Shown below**

   01:19:32,314 INFO  - [DominoChanges] CTGDJE074I Local Client Session successfully created.
   01:19:32,314 INFO  - [DominoChanges] CTGDJE013I Successfully connected to Domino Server: Name='', Version='Release 9.0.1|October 14, 2013             ', Platform='Windows/32'.
   01:19:32,517 INFO  - CTGDIS087I Iterating.
   01:19:32,533 ERROR - [UpdateAD] CTGDIS810E handleException - cannot handle exception , update 
   java.lang.Exception: CTGDIS143E No criteria can be built from input (no link criteria specified).
          at com.ibm.di.server.SearchCriteria.buildCriteria(SearchCriteria.java:1093)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLineComponent.update(AssemblyLineComponent.java:1676)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.msExecuteNextConnector(AssemblyLine.java:3683)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainStep(AssemblyLine.java:3308)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainLoop(AssemblyLine.java:2944)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainLoop(AssemblyLine.java:2927)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeAL(AssemblyLine.java:2896)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.run(AssemblyLine.java:1296)
   01:19:32,533 ERROR - CTGDIS266E Error in NextConnectorOperation. Exception occurred: java.lang.Exception: CTGDIS143E No criteria can be built from input (no link criteria specified). 
   java.lang.Exception: CTGDIS143E No criteria can be built from input (no link criteria specified).
          at com.ibm.di.server.SearchCriteria.buildCriteria(SearchCriteria.java:1093)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLineComponent.update(AssemblyLineComponent.java:1676)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.msExecuteNextConnector(AssemblyLine.java:3683)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainStep(AssemblyLine.java:3308)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainLoop(AssemblyLine.java:2944)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeMainLoop(AssemblyLine.java:2927)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.executeAL(AssemblyLine.java:2896)
          at com.ibm.di.server.AssemblyLine.run(AssemblyLine.java:1296)
   01:19:32,548 INFO  - CTGDIS100I Printing the Connector statistics.
   01:19:32,548 INFO  -  [DominoChanges] Get:1
   01:19:32,548 INFO  -  [IF - add or delete] Branch True:0, Branch False:1
   01:19:32,564 INFO  -  [SendAlerts] Calls: 0
   01:19:32,564 INFO  -  [ELSE - modify] Branch True:1, Branch False:0
   01:19:32,564 INFO  -  [UpdateAD] Errors:1
   01:19:32,564 INFO  - CTGDIS104I Total: Get:1, Errors:2.
   01:19:32,564 INFO  - CTGDIS101I Finished printing the Connector statistics.
   01:19:32,564 ERROR - CTGDIS077I Failed with error: CTGDIS143E No criteria can be built from input (no link criteria specified)..

Need your help about this error, i am a new TDI user too

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first errors, the UserID is listed as "null" which probably is the issue.  You'll need to authenticate to the server using an ID that has Admin rights on the server. Once you get past that, see what else happens as I'm guessing that might clear up the rest as well.